# Create 2 different user types in Django using One to Many relationship

Tags: python, django

I am creating a basketball statistic application where I would like to have two different user types, Coach and Player. I want the coach to be able to log in and view the stats for his players only. Therefore one coach will have many players. I want to be able to create user profiles for each coach and display their players only and not all of the players in the database. As of now, I have created the user profiles that displays all of the registered users but I am confused on how to separate the two users so that the players will be under the coaches. Also, how can I display all of the players that is listed under a coach in HTML? Thank you!!!

Models.py view:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save


class UserProfile(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
school_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
description = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
city = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
state = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
website = models.URLField(default='')
phone = models.IntegerField(default=0)
jersey_number = models.IntegerField(default=0)
image = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_image', blank=True)
position = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
height = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
weight = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
grade = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
background_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_image', blank=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.user.username


def create_profile(sender, **kwargs):
if kwargs['created']:
    user_profile = UserProfile.objects.create(user=kwargs['instance'])

post_save.connect(create_profile, sender=User)
```

Views.py:

```
@login_required(login_url='login')
def view_profile(request, pk=None):
if pk:
    user = User.objects.get(pk=pk)
else:
    user = request.user
args = {'user': user}
return render(request, 'accounts/profile.html', args)
```

So I am logged in as a user and it displays both players. I would like for it to only display player1, then log in as another coach and it displays player2.

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Django Admin View:
So if I log in under each user, it will display all of the users. For example: I want to log in under 1 user (Coach) and for it to display Players 1-4, then log in under another coach, and for it to display Players 5-7.
[![enter image description here][2]][2]

HTML view:

```
<div class="column middle">
                <table id="roster" class="table table-bordered table-hover table-condensed"><!--add roster-->
                    <h2>Roster</h2>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="col">#</th>
                            <th scope="col">Player Name</th>
                            <th scope="col">Position</th>
                            <th scope="col">Grade</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                                {% for user in users %}
                        <tr>
                            <td class="number">{{ user.userprofile.jersey_number }} </td>
                            <td class="name">
                                {% if user.userprofile.image %}
                                <img src="{{ user.userprofile.image.url }}" width="60" height="75" vspace="10">
                                {% endif %}
                                <a href="{% url 'view_profile_with_pk' pk=user.pk %}">
                                {{ user.userprofile.name }}
                                </a>
                            </td>
                            <td class="position">{{ user.userprofile.position }}</td>
                            <td class="grade">{{ user.userprofile.grade }}</td>
                        </tr>
                                {% endfor %}

                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the same model for both coaches and players, separate them out. You can also create an abstraction of the team which is a good idea as you'll probably want to have the ability to have multiple coaches per team or have coaches that coach one team one year and another team the next.

models.py

```
class Coach(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField("auth.User")
    # ... Other info

class Team(models.Model):
     coach = models.OneToOneField(Coach)
     # ... Other info

class Player(models.Model):
     user = models.OneToOneField("auth.User")
     team = models.ForeignKey(Team)
     # ... Other info
```

Then if you want a players coach:

```
player = Player.objects.get(...)
players_coach = player.team.coach
```

Or if you want to get a coaches players:

```
coach = Coach.objects.get(...)
coaches_players = coach.team.player_set.all()
```

This also allows you to easily change the relationship between coaches and players like change the Foreign key between coach and team to a ManyToManyField in order to allow many coaches per team and coaches to coach multiple teams over the years.

------------- Heres how you might implement it ----------------

```
@login_required(login_url='login')
def view_profile(request, pk=None):
    if pk:
        user = User.objects.get(pk=pk)
    else:
        user = request.user

    context = {}

    if user.coach is not None:
        # User is a coach
        coach = user.coach
        coaches_players = coach.team.player_set.all()
        context["coaches_players"] = coaches_players
    elif user.player is not None:
        # User is a player
        player = user.player
        players_coach = player.team.coach
        context["players_coach"] = players_coach

    # Depending on which variables are None and which aren't, the user is a coach or a player.
    # If 'player' and 'players_coach' aren't None, then the user is a player and you now have their player object in 'player' and their coach in 'players_coach'.
    # If 'coach' and 'coaches_players' aren't None, then the user is a coach and you now have their coach object in 'coach' and their players in 'coaches_players'.

    context["user"] = user
    return render(request, 'accounts/profile.html', context)
```

Then in HTML template:

```
{% for player in coaches_players %}
<p>{{ player }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: " Thank you for that information. I was able to add the Coach, Player, and Team users in the django admin. Can you clarify the second part of your answer for me? Where should I put the "player = Player.objects.get(...)
players_coach = player.team.coach" ? Under views.py? Should I use the same view_profile function as I stated above and incorporate your information, or should I define a new function? I am trying to get it to work where I can now view the roster of Coach 1 when I log in."

Comment: How exactly should I write the function on the views.py page? Can you help with that as well? Thank you.

Comment: I would love to help you. However, where you put the last part of the question is totally dependant on your app. That's simply implementation so whereever you need to retrieve the players and coaches is where you would put the respective query.

Based on the view you supplied, I'll try to show where I would put it in my answer as an update.

Comment: @ian.....Using your example, how would I display all of the players that are listed under a coach in HTML. I updated my question and added my HTML view. Instead of {% for user in users %}, how would I do it with the new classes that you helped me with?  I tried {% for coach in coach %} and a couple of other ways, but nothing seems to work to display all of the players under one coach.Thank you.

Comment: Add the list of players to context, send context to the template, then loop over them. See my updated answer

Comment: You have been so much help, Ian. Thank you very much. I am just learning Django and html so I am very new to this. To loop over them, what terminology would I use? Can you provide an example to loop over them in html? I swear this is my last question. Thank you very much.

Comment: Not a problem. Here's how to loop over them in HTML:

<div>
{% for player in coaches_players %}
<p>{{ player }}</p>
{% endfor %}
</div>

Comment: When you're satisfied, would you please accept my answer?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you for that information.