# How can i auth_group for user in django

Tags: python, django

i have a question about django framework that how can i write User Model for each user registed have their function. Like: grab have 2 signals are driver and customer. How can i do that or anyone have example code about that. Thank for supported me!!

Comment: Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51882213/create-2-different-user-types-in-django-using-one-to-many-relationship) for example.

Comment: @dirkgroten Thanks, But i still dont know how to navigater user to exactly function

Comment: I don’t understand “navigater user to exactly function”. What function? What’s “navigater”? You have to be more specific with your problem, write a  [mcve], show us some code.

Comment: i mean each user like customer or driver have their function :D

Comment: Again what do you mean by “their function”? If you have separate user profiles, when a user logs in, you check which type of user it is and do whatever you need to do for that type of user. We can’t answer your question if you don’t show us what you’re trying to do with your code.

Comment: Sorry for my bad English, i am trying to describe my issue :(. Thanks for your answer. I want each user have their behavior like customer can oder car, driver can drive and get order. Like that, thanks. Again sorry for my bad English @dirkgroten

Comment: Ok. But the issue here is how can we help? You have to start somewhere and write code. We can’t help without seeing your code. I could say write a Django view and in the view write “if request.user.user_type == “driver”: return HttpResponse(“you’re a driver”)” but without knowing what you really need that would probably be useless.